Does the equation of eigenvalues tell the equation of the matrix?
If $\lambda$'s (eigenvalues) satisfy an polynomial equation, can I derive the same equation for the matrix?
To be specific, if I have $\lambda^2 = 1$, can I get $A^2 = I$?
I know the converse is definitely true. That is, if $A^2 = I$, I must have $\lambda^2=1$. This can be proved by multiplying any eigenvector $\mathbf{x}$ on the right.
$$
A^2\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x} \Rightarrow 
\lambda^2\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x} \Rightarrow
\lambda^2 =1.
$$
I suspect the orders matter. For simplicity, let's first assume the polynomial equation of $\lambda$'s (can I call it the characteristic equation?) has the same order with the matrix $A$. Any further discussion is welcome(e.g. what will happen if they have different order?).
Update:
A polynomial equation of $\lambda$ (the same order with the matrix) may or may not be the characteristic polynomial. An answer below shows an example: $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &1\\
0 &1\end{bmatrix}$.

See Cayley Hamilton theorem.

IF $A$ is $2 \times 2$ with $1$ and $-1$ both as eigen values then $A^{2}=I$.

The statement is only true for diagonalisable matrices. Consider the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Its only eigenvalue is $1$, so $\lambda^2 = 1$ for all eigenvalues. Still, $A^2 \neq I$.

As this answer shows, "think about Jordan blocks" is often a good approach to finding counterexamples if no symmetry condition is present.

$A$ is one of the standard counterexamples in linear algebra. The others being nilpotents, idempotents, and rotation matrices over the reals.

Great example. But how to prove that is true for diagonalizable matrices? I have read the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, but found those are different things.

Write $A = TDT^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal. Now apply the polynomial.

I see. It eventually leads to $Tp(D)T^{-1}$. Thanks!
